# How can I make a query in mongoose and node.js to count users depending on a value (similar to mysql distinct)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a following collection in mongoose:

```
_id
username
problem_no
```

and `problem_no` can be either 1, 2 or 3.

I want to write a webservice in node.js that will return me a json with a number of records distinguished by the problem_no, so for example:

```
"1" : "17", "2" : "13", "3" : "0"
```

I so far tried sth like:

```
 var User            = require('./model.js');

 app.get('/countAll', function(req, res){


    userModel
    // Uses Mongoose schema to run the search (empty conditions)
    var query = User.count({});
    query.exec(function(err, users){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

but I have no idea how to introduce here the problem_no.. 
I will appreciate any hints, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible like you expect, i think you have to make 3 queries for each `problem_no`:

```
User.find({problem_no:1})
    .count()
    .exec(function (err, count) {
        res.send({user_problem_no_1: count})
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDb 3.6 and newer, you can leverage the use of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator and a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline to get the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "$substr": [ "$problem_no", 0, -1 ] }, /* convert to string */
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "k": "$_id",
                    "v": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
        } 
    }    
])
```

---

For older versions, take advantage of the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage to evaluate the counts based on the `problem_no` value, something like the following:

```
var pipeline = [    
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": null,             
            "problem_no1_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$problem_no", 1 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "problem_no2_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$problem_no", 2 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "problem_no3_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$problem_no", 3 ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }  
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,           
            "1": "$problem_no1_count",
            "2": "$problem_no2_count",
            "3": "$problem_no3_count"                
        }
    }
];

User.aggregate(pipeline)
    .exec(function (err, result){
        if (err) /* Handle error */
        res.send(result);
    });
```